# Product of 2 sequences where 1 sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Suppose $a_nb_n \rightarrow c$ $ \land$ $ a_n\rightarrow a>0$. If $|b_n|\leq M $ is bounded, does that mean $b_n$ is convergent?

Since:
$$|b_n-\frac{c}{a}|\leq \frac{M}{a} |a-a_n|+\frac{1}{a}|a_nb_n-c|$$

Comment: Your claim is indeed correct and you've also found a proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the condition $b_n$ bounded is not necessary.

Since $a_nb_n$ converge then it is bounded $|a_nb_n|\le M$ with $M>0$

Since $a_n$ converge to $a>0$ then $\exists n_0\mid \forall n>n_0,\ |a_n|\ge \frac a2>0$

Thus $\forall n>n_0,\ M\ge|a_nb_n|\ge|a_n||b_n|\ge\frac a2|b_n|\implies |b_n|\le \frac{2M}a$

The rest of the proof holds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, let $c_n=a_nb_n$. Eventuelly $a_n\ne 0$ so $b_n = c_n/a_n$ and both $c_n$ and $a_n$ are convergent.